# PHP route different NGINX cluster

Tags: nginx, php

I have a PHP application that uses ZF2 - so all requests go to index.php and it sorts out it's own routing.

I'd like to configure the following setup:

Requests to `www.example.com` go to the servers configured in the `cluster_web` block.
Requests to `www.example.com/admin` go to the servers configured in the `cluser_admin` block.

How would this be achieved using NGINX?

The configuration currently looks as follows:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/cluster.conf

```
upstream cluster_web {
    server 192.168.0.10:9000;
    server 192.168.0.11:9000;
}

upstream cluster_admin {
    server 192.168.0.20:9000;
    server 192.168.0.21:9000;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    root         /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri =404;

        # how do I split this out?
        fastcgi_pass    cluster_web;

        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I probably need a `location /admin` in there somewhere? But not sure where.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I may have resolved this but I'm not sure it is the most optimised method.

```
# web requests
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    root         /var/www/public;

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass    cluster_web;

        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}

# admin requests
server {
    listen       8080;

    root         /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass    cluster_admin;

        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on optimising this would be appreciated.